# There's $120$ balls with $ X $ (random variable) of them being white. $k$ balls are sampled, find probability for first ball sampled being white

Tags: probability, random-variables, proof-explanation

**Problem:**
In a box there are $120$ balls with $ X $ of them being white and $ 120 - X $ being red for **random variable $X$**. Given that $ E[ X] = 30 $, we are taking out $ k  $ balls randomly and with returning ( we return each ball we take out, so for each ball there is equal probability every time we take out a ball ), for $ k \geq 2 $.
Let $ Y $ be the number of white balls in the sample that was taken out.
What is the probability of the first ball taken out being white?

**Note:** This was the first question of an old exam and there were more questions that were based on it in the exam later on ( so it might be the case that we don't need to use $ k $ here. ), none of them helped in inferring the reasoning for the answer to this problem.

**The solution was:**
$ E[ \frac{X}{120}] = \frac{1}{4} $, hence the probability of the first ball being white is $ \frac{1}{4} $

**Question:**
I tried different things, among them being attempting to use binomial ,negative-binomial, hyper-geometric distributions in the problem, but I kept getting stuck because I don't know what $ X $ is since it is a random variable.
Then I tried getting ahead with equations such as:
$ E[ X] = \sum_{i=1}^{120} x P(X = x) $ ,  $ E[ X] = \sum_{i=1}^{120} P(X \geq i) $ , or a different equation in which I can use $ E[aX] = a \cdot E[X] $ but I was unable to proceed.

Do you have any explanation for the answer? I'm unable to retrace the steps necessary to arrive to it so I can't figure out how to arrive at the answer.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Let $X_i$ be the indicator value for the $i^{th}$ ball (suppose we draw all $120$ in order, say, without replacement).  Then $E[X_i]=E[X_j]=p$ for all pairs $(i,j)$, where $p$ is the probability that a given selection is White,  and $E[X]=\sum E[X_i]$

Comment: Note:  the problem is oddly worded.  $k$ seems to have nothing to do with it, and $E[X]=30$ is never stated in the problem (you assert it in the body of your post but you don't explain why you think it is true).

Comment: @lulu It is written here $k\ge 2$: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/number-of-balls-is-a-random-variable-and-only-the-expectation-value-is-known.1047575/#post-6825363

Comment: Ok.  Well, neither $Y$ nor $k$ have any relevance to the problem.  The desired result just follows from linearity of expexctation.

Comment: This was the problem ( it's without errors ) and it indeed confused me. I understand the solution now though because of what you proposed ( though, I didn't consider using an indicator variable for an event that looks at the value of $ X $ , very nice ). Thanks!

Comment: Here is an approach that follows similar reasoning to the OP.

For $x\in \{0,...,120\} $ we have $\mathbb{P}(W|X=x)=\frac{x}{120}$. So, from the total law, $$\mathbb{P}(W)=\sum_{x=0}^{120}\mathbb{P}(W|X=x)\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\frac{1}{120}\sum_{x=0}^{120}x\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\frac{1}{120}\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{4}$$